# Sending request from python object

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a list of tuples that I want to iterate through and send a http request via the python requests module.

```
api_schedule = [
{'destination': (51.490527, 0.267840), 'id': 'trial_a', 'origin': (51.430732, 0.239308)},
{'destination': (51.429488, 0.239060), 'id': 'trial_b', 'origin': (51.490518, 0.267578)}]
```

The origin and destination coordinates are proving difficult to format correctly. The Google Directions API expects them in the format `lat,lng` where the `lat` and `lng` are `float`

I iterate through the list of dictionaries like so:

```
for pair in api_schedule:
    departure_time = time.time()
    origin_lat = str(pair['origin'][0])
    origin_lng = "," + str(pair['origin'][1])
    origin = origin_lat + origin_lng
    destination_lat = str(pair['destination'][0])
    destination_lng = "," + str(pair['destination'][1])
    destination = destination_lat + destination_lng
    params = {
    "origin" : origin,
    "destination" : destination
    "key" : api_Key,
    "departure_time" : departure_time,
    "mode" : mode
    }
    request = requests.Request('GET', url_raw, params=params).prepare()
    print request.url
```

However, this returns `%2C` in place of `,`:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=51.430732%2C0.239308&destination=51.490527&destination=0.26784`

How do I iterate through a list of tuples like this and use requests to formula the parameters correctly?

When I try without the above manipulation, requests views the origin and destination data as lists and thus creates two params like so:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=51.430732&origin=0.239308
```

Desired output:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=51.430732,0.239308&destination=51.490527,0.26784
```

Comment: What would be the required result?

Comment: The first question helped me understand why it wasn't working. The field is being converted to a list. This question is how do I solve this problem for this application.

Comment: Please define ' formula the parameters correctly': What is the expected URL?

Comment: I have added the desired output. `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=51.430732,0.239308&destination=51.490527,0.26784
` instead of `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=51.430732&origin=0.239308` or `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=51.430732%2C0.239308&destination=51.490527&destination=0.26784`

Comment: `%2C` is *entirely correct and expected* in a URL. Google will decode that for you. If you were to use your 'desired output' URL in a browser, your *browser* would also encode the comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=51.430732%2C0.239308&destination=51.490527,0.26784` and `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=51.430732,0.239308&destination=51.490527,0.26784` are identical.

[It is correct to use `%2C` instead of `,` in an URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).  Your preparation of `params` is OK.